# Присвоение выбранного цвета через js

Tags: color, css, javascript

Приветствую.

Есть список статусов с круглешками, которым надо задать фон, при нажатии на такой круглешок выскакивает окошко рядом с ним для выбора цвета.

Код выбора цвета:

```
// При нажатии
$('.color-status').bind('click', function () {

// Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
var title = $(this).data("target"); // передаем id элемента, который надо открыть
var statuscolor = $(this).data("statuscolor"); // передаем id элемента, которому надо будет присвоить новый цвет.

// Показываем блок
$(this).after($(title));
$(title).slideDown(500);
});

cp = ColorPicker(document.getElementById('slide'), document.getElementById('picker'), 
function(hex, hsv, rgb, mousePicker, mouseSlide) {
currentColor = hex;
                                    ColorPicker.positionIndicators(
                                        document.getElementById('slide-indicator'),
                                        document.getElementById('picker-indicator'),
mouseSlide, mousePicker
);

                                    document.getElementById('status-id-'+ statuscolor +'').style.backgroundColor = hex;
                                    document.getElementById('color').value = hex;

});
cp.setHex('#D4EDFB');
```

Должно, по идее, работать, но не работает!

**Помогите, пожалуйста!**

Comment: У вас плагин не работает? Что в консоли пишет?

Comment: Сам плагин работает отлично, просто именно я не могу передать выбранный цвет в элемент, у которого, например, id status-id-50. Уже как не пытался, не хочет передавать, и все тут.  =(